# How to upload a binary blob with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, httprequest, blob

I have captured some video with the webcam and placed it on a blob. After that I do 2 things:

1. Save it to a local file
2. Send it in a POST request

The file saved works perfectly, but the data in the post requests arrives as text to my C# HttpListener.

Is there something I need to do BEFORE I send the blob, or AFTER I received it?

version 1:

```
function uploadBlob( aBlob ) {
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'https://TTTEServer:1300/TTTE?Action=UploadVideo',
  data: aBlob,
  datatype: 'dataType'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```

version 2:

```
function uploadBlob(blob){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fname', 'test.txt');
    fd.append('data', event.target.result);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://TTTEServer:1300/TTTE?Action=UploadVideo',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false
    }).done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
};      
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}
```

The function for downloading the blobl works well:

```
function downloadBlob(blob) {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.display = 'none';
  a.href = url;
  a.download = 'test.webm';
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  setTimeout(function() {
  document.body.removeChild(a);
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: To POST data as binary, I believe you need to set your content type as application/octet.

Comment: I tried it. It still sends text, unfortunately.

Comment: `fetch(url, {method: 'post', body: blob})`

Comment: Why do you convert it to a dataURI? Send it directly as *multipart/form-data*. To do so, in you XHR version, append your Blob as binary in the FormData object: `fd.append(fieldName, blob, filename)` and forget about `FileReader.readAsDataURL`, most of the time you don't need it.